# Lightning Object binding via attribute

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-attribute

Can someone explain me, why object binding is not working?

**cmpOne.cmp**

```
<aura:component extensible="true" abstract="true" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="testObject" type="Account" access="global"/>

    <span>
        {!v.body}
    </span>
</aura:component>
```

**cmpOneFirst.cmp**

```
<aura:component extends="c:cmpOne" access="global">  
    <ui:inputText value="{!v.testObject.Name}" /> 
</aura:component>
```

**cmpOneSecond.cmp**

```
<aura:component extends="c:cmpOne" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="types" type="Aura.Component[]" access="global"/>
    {!v.types}
</aura:component>
```

**cmpOneThird.cmp**

```
<aura:component extends="c:cmpOne" access="global">
    // value of field should be changed, as  this value  is changing  in  inner component
    {!v.testObject.Name} <br/> 

    <c:cmpOneSecond>
        <aura:set attribute="types">
            <c:cmpOneFirst testObject="{!v.testObject}"/>
        </aura:set>
    </c:cmpOneSecond>
</aura:component>
```

No controllers.

Desired behaviour: when  you change value of  name field in **cmpOneFirst.cmp**, new value is displayed in **cmpOneThird.cmp**

If you change type of **testObject** attribute from **Account** to **String** - binding works. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had this happen before and was able to resolve it by using a `default` attribute to predefine the keys/values of the object fields that you want to bind on.

Try something like this:

```
<aura:attribute name="testObject" type="Account" 
                default="{ 'sobjectType':'Account', 'Name' : ''}"
                access="global"/>
```